# Rails 4 - Heroku Sqlite3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm having some trouble with Herouku. I can't push because of the following error:

```
Gem files will remain installed in  /tmp/build_2jdec30lsc3bu/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2jdec30lsc3bu/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

And I can't solve it.

I have tried the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And I keep getting the same error. I have even tried to remove sqlite3 completely. Same annoying error. I made sure to push my changes before running `git push heroku master`. Any ideas? Or I will probably give up on Heroku...

Comment: Have you done bundle install recently?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. Feels like I've tried everything... Not liking Heroku atm.

Comment: You'll learn to love Heroku. It's excellent in many ways. After bundle install, can you do `git status`? Is there any change in Gemfile and Gemfile.lock?

Comment: This problem (and a whole bunch of problems that you probably have but don't know about yet) would go away with if you stopped developing on top of SQLite when you're deploying on top of PostgreSQL. Yes, SQLite is the Rails default but it is, quite frankly, a stupid default that should never have been done. Your development and production environments should match as closely as possible, no ORM or toolset will protect from you from database differences.

Comment: I suggest closing the question because the problem was due to the original poster [being in the wrong Git branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497012/rails-4-heroku-sqlite3-error#comment25440797_17497474).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar problems before.  This works for me in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'pg', group: [:production]
```

Also, in your local git checkout, execute the command `heroku config`.  Confirm that the output has the following environment variables set:

```
RACK_ENV:                     production
RAILS_ENV:                    production
```

Give that a shot.  Does it work for you?

Comment: `heroku config` returns `has no config vars`. How could I fix that?

Comment: Tried your code and added RACK_ENV & RAILS_ENV in my heroku config. No luck. :(

Comment: I've definitely been in the wrong branch before.  ;-)  I hope you're off and running again!

Comment: It's not recommended to use two different database configurations in production and development. It will increase debug effort because the app may work fine in development but not in production, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
heroku rake db:reset
heroku rake db:migrate
```